# mem_fn() doesn't work on templates?

Tags: c++, c++11, clang

I'm playing with C++11 and found `mem_fn()`. But seems it doesn't work on templates?

```
 vector<int> vec;
 auto push_back = mem_fn(&vector<int>::push_back);
```

Compile error:

```
memfn.cc:18:22: error: no matching function for call to 'mem_fn'
auto push_back = mem_fn(&vector<int>::push_back);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't skip the `#include`. Note that it also fails to compile if you remove `mem_fn`, since push_back is overloaded.

Comment: I don't think you're allowed to form member function pointers to standard library functions, because implementations are allowed to add extra default arguments and additional overloads.

Comment: @Simple interesting, do you know where in the standard I should look for this?

Comment: @Oktalist See 17.6.5.5 [member.functions]: *An implementation may declare additional non-virtual member function signatures within a class:
— by adding arguments with default values to a member function signature;
— by replacing a member function signature with default values by two or more member function signa-
tures with equivalent behavior; and
— by adding a member function signature for a member function name.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vector<>::push_back` is an overloaded function, you need to choose one particular overload using a cast:

```
auto push_back = mem_fn(static_cast<void(vector<int>::*)(int const&)>(&vector<int>::push_back));
```

Alternatively, since you use C++11, you can use a lambda function:

```
auto push_back = [](vector<int>& v, int i) { v.push_back(i); };
```